# renderHook - mock calls after rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have problem with spying mock calls after hook is rerender. Here's my test. I log subscribe and unsubscribe function to console and it clearly runs 2 times during test, parameters also match. My hook has useEffect with dependency [sheet]. I change sheet object and run rerender() (also tried rerender({sheet}). It says that runs one time. Any suggestions?

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { DataHubService } from "./DataHubService";
import { useCurrentDataSubscription } from "./useCurrentDataSubscription.hook";
import { renderHookWrapper } from "./utils/renderHookWrapper";

const mockSubscribeAsync = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
const mockUnsubscribeAsync = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());

// https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#spying-on-the-constructor
jest.mock("./DataHubService", () => {
  return {
    DataHubService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        connection: { on: jest.fn() },
        subscribeAsync: mockSubscribeAsync,
        unsubscribeAsync: mockUnsubscribeAsync
      };
    })
  };
});

describe("useCurrentDataSubscription", () => {
  test("should call unsubscribe when sheet change", () => {
    // Arrange
    const mockHubConnection = new DataHubService("test");

    let sheet: any = {
      Id: 1,
      Name: "Test"
    };

    // Act

    const { rerender } = renderHook(
      () => useCurrentDataSubscription(mockHubConnection, sheet, []),
      {
        wrapper: renderHookWrapper
      }
    );

    sheet = {
      Id: 2,
      Name: "new Test sheet"
    };

    rerender();

    // Assert
    expect(mockUnsubscribeAsync).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

useCurrentDataSubscription.hook.ts

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { subscribe, unsubscribe } from "./redux/features/currentData-slice";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./redux/hooks";

export function useCurrentDataSubscription(
  hubConnection: any,
  sheet: any,
  alarm: any[]
) {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const currentSubscribeDataRef = useRef<any>({ values: {} });
  const prevSubscribeDataRef = useRef<any>({ values: {} });

  const sendSubscribe = useCallback(
    async (subscribeData: any) => {
      try {
        console.group(">>> Subscribe");
        console.dir(JSON.stringify(subscribeData));
        console.groupEnd();
        dispatch(subscribe(subscribeData));
        await hubConnection?.subscribeAsync(subscribeData);
      } catch (error) {}
    },
    [dispatch, hubConnection]
  );

  const sendUnsubscribe = useCallback(
    async (unsubscribeData: any) => {
      try {
        console.group(">>> UnSubscribe");
        console.dir(JSON.stringify(unsubscribeData));
        console.groupEnd();

        dispatch(unsubscribe(unsubscribeData));
        await hubConnection?.unsubscribeAsync(unsubscribeData);
      } catch (error) {}
    },
    [dispatch, hubConnection]
  );

  const handleSubscribeUnsubscribe = useCallback(() => {
    // real app call sub/unsub with parameters calculated based on currentSubscribeDataRef & prevSubscribeDataRef
    // call sub/unsub with default values for simplicity
    sendSubscribe({ values: {} });
    sendUnsubscribe({ value: {} });
  }, [sendSubscribe, sendUnsubscribe]);

  const getSubscribeData = useCallback(
    (sheet: any, alarm: any) => {
      /// parsing sheet object and return object with values - not important
      return { values: {} };
    },
    [sheet, alarm]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    currentSubscribeDataRef.current = getSubscribeData(sheet, alarm);
    handleSubscribeUnsubscribe();
    return () => {
      prevSubscribeDataRef.current = getSubscribeData(sheet, alarm);
    };
  }, [sheet, alarm, getSubscribeData, handleSubscribeUnsubscribe]);

  return {
    subscribeData: currentSubscribeDataRef.current,
    prevSubscribeData: prevSubscribeDataRef.current
  };
}
```

This is how log looks like in real app. However assertion doesn't reflect that. When I remove rerender() it log one time subscribe and unsubscribe functions.

```
>  
> 
> > >>> SubscribeAsync   console.dir
> >       '{"values":{"TWSRV":{"variables":[{"name":"variable1","mode":1}],"subscription":64},"TWSRV2":{"variables":[{"name":"variable1","mode":1},{"name":"variable2","mode":1}],"subscription":64}}}'
> > 
> >       console.group
> >           >>> UnSubscribeAsync
> >       console.dir
> >           '{"values":{}}'
> >     // sheet change - call rerender
> >     
> >       console.group
> >           >>> SubscribeAsync
> >       console.dir
> >           '{"values":{}}'
> >     
> >       console.group
> >           >>> UnSubscribeAsync
> >       console.dir
> >           '{"values":{"TWSRV":{"variables":[{"name":"variable1"}]},"TWSRV2":{"variables":[{"name":"variable1"},{"name":"variable2"}]}}}'
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, show the code of `useCurrentDataSubscription` hook and `DataHubService`

Comment: Tried to reproduce code on CodeSandbox but 'jest.mock is not a function' stopped me. https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-cloud-c6mr0q?file=/src/useCurrentDataSubscription.hook.tsx 
However I found that useCurrentDataSubscription hook use dispatch() function and it somehow cause test to failed.